# Magento 1.9 Custom Module not activating

Tags: magento-1.9

I have a custom module that I can't get to activate. I have the following in app/etc/modules/DBCustom_Quote:

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <DBCustom_Quote>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </DBCustom_Quote>
    </modules>
</config>
```

And the following in app/code/local/DBCustom/Quote/etc/config.xml:

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <DBCustom_Quote>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </DBCustom_Quote>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <dbcustom_quote>
                <class>DBCustom_Quote_Model</class>
            </dbcustom_quote>
        </models>
        <events>
            <ophirah_qquoteadv_admin_swith2Quote_after>
                <observers>
                    <dbcustom_sendemail>
                        <class>DBCustom_Quote_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>sendEmail</method>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                    </dbcustom_sendemail>
                </observers>
            </ophirah_qquoteadv_admin_swith2Quote_after>
        </events>
    </global>
</config>
```

But it won't show up in Admin->Configuration->Advanced->Advanced. I have tried flushing the cache multiple times through the admin Cache Management page and through the CLI and none of it works. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Hey Did you check your module entry in "core_resource" table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

Firstly the `app/etc/modules/DBCustom_Quote` needs to be `app/etc/modules/DBCustom_Quote.xml` - note the missing .xml file extension.

Secondly, you need the xml file declaration at the top of any XML files:

So, `app/etc/modules/DBCustom_Quote.xml` is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <DBCustom_Quote>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </DBCustom_Quote>
    </modules>
</config>
```

and `app/code/local/DBCustom/Quote/etc/config.xml` is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <DBCustom_Quote>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </DBCustom_Quote>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <dbcustom_quote>
                <class>DBCustom_Quote_Model</class>
            </dbcustom_quote>
        </models>
        <events>
            <ophirah_qquoteadv_admin_swith2Quote_after>
                <observers>
                    <dbcustom_sendemail>
                        <class>DBCustom_Quote_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>sendEmail</method>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                    </dbcustom_sendemail>
                </observers>
            </ophirah_qquoteadv_admin_swith2Quote_after>
        </events>
    </global>
</config>
```

Finally, flush/clear the cache. This is essential after making any XML changes.

This is tested and working for me on Magento 1.9.x

Comment: Of course, the module DBCustom_Quote wasn't an xml file. It's always some stupid little thing that's so obvious, you don't bother checking it. Thank you very much.